# Python quiz game

Tags: python-2.7

Hello guys i am a new guy in programming and i would like to make a question about a program i am trying to create. It is a simple program i just want to make this thing work and i cant :P. I think it is very simple for you to understand so i wont explain something more, so here is the code:

```
print "Quiz game"

counter = 0

print "1) 2 + 2?"

print "A. 3"
print "B. 4"
print "C. 6"
print "D. 8"

x = raw_input("Answer: ")
if x == "b" or x == "B":
    x = "correct"

print "2) 3 + 2?"

print "A. 3"
print "B. 6"
print "C. 9"
print "D. 5"

x = raw_input("Answer: ")
if x == "d" or x == "D":
    x = "correct"

print "3) 5 + 4?)"

print "A. 4"
print "B. 5"
print "C. 6"
print "D. 9"

x = raw_input("Answer: ")
if x == "d" or x == "D":
    x = "correct"

while x == "correct":
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter >= 1:
        print "Your score is good"
        x = raw_input("Press enter to quit")        
    else:
        print "Your score is not good"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please Explain what you are trying to do with your code because _Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._.

Comment: You are continually overwriting the variable "x".  When you reach the loop at the end, `x` is either `"correct"`, at which point you'll have an infinite loop, or it is the result of the last `raw_input` statement, and the script quits immediately. Try incrementing the score each time you see a correct answer and do away with the `while x == "correct"` in the final score checking logic.

Comment: [Link to SO page explaining minimal, complete, and verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: + Richard Erickson Sorry about this you are right. So the problem is that when i am running this program the only question that is working is the last one, none of the above i think the problem is that i am using the same variable over and over again but i tried to change the variable to all of the above but still the same. Also the else statement doesnt work at all.

Comment: +Brian McFarland So you are saying that instead of the while loop at the end, i should try for example score += 1 for every correct answer? Isn't it a way to make this work like that? Cause i think it is not fully wrong the way i wrote it :/

Answer (score 0):

Its ok guys it is running!!! :) Thank you for your time

```
    print "Quiz game"

counter = 0

print "1) Poso kanei 2 + 2?"

print "A. 3"
print "B. 4"
print "C. 6"
print "D. 8"

x = raw_input("Apantish: ")
if x == "b" or x == "B":
    counter += 1

print "2) Poso kanei 3 + 2?"

print "A. 3"
print "B. 6"
print "C. 9"
print "D. 5"

x = raw_input("Apantish: ")
if x == "d" or x == "D":
    counter += 1

print "3) Poso kanei 5 + 4?)"

print "A. 4"
print "B. 5"
print "C. 6"
print "D. 9"

x = raw_input("Apantish: ")
if x == "d" or x == "D":
    counter += 1

while counter >= 1:
        print "Your score is good"
        x = raw_input("Press enter to quit")
        break;
else:
        print "Your score is not good"
```